# Typescript function type not enforcing the same strictness as return type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a function type with a return type (Object) to enforce functions implementing it to return the exact object properties defined in the return type.

However the compiler is not being strict about the returned object and allows extra properties that are not defined in the returned object type.

```js
interface Obj {
  foo: string;
}

type Func = () => Obj;

const fn: Func = () => {
  return {
    foo: 'bar',
    blah: '', // compiler does not show an error
  };
};
```

[Example in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZGAe2IC5kBnMKUAcwG48BfPPMATwAcUAxAVxAJkAXmQAKAJSiAfGixM8CYiGpEQFAUNETpIufkJQIYflBC4ChIqQoBydHCh2ANFcLoANnAAW918gA9IHIygC2XMCe0MgAJsQQlMggxGBUPsQA7shwFtBQxFBWzEwlQA)

In contrast, if the return type `Obj` is specified in the `fn` function, the compiler shows an error.

```js
interface Obj {
  foo: string;
}

const fn = (): Obj => {
  return {
    foo: 'bar',
    blah: '', // compiler shows an error
  };
};
```

[Example in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZGAe2IC5kBnMKUAcwG48BfPPBYkaokZAXmQAKAJQUM2PgD5cBZFAhgArlF75ChEuWQBydHCjaANLMLoANnAAWFbUeQB6e8g4BbAA7Az0KpeIB3SmQ4XmgoYihZZiYooA)

Can somebody explain why TS handles these cases differently?
Is there a way to have the return type strictness while using a function type?

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, the return type of the anonymous function is defined dynamically as follow: `{ foo: string; blah: string; }`. This type is *compatible* with the type `Obj` as it has all the required properties of `Obj` (and more, but that's enough to be considered *compatible*, as "structural typing is a way of relating types based solely on their members", from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

In the end, the `Func` type is compatible with the silently defined type of the anonymous function `() => { foo: string; blah: string; }`, so an "implicit conversion" takes place and it compiles.

In the second example, the signature enforces the return type of the anonymous function itself, so the returned object is a literal that's supposed to be *exactly* of type `Obj`. Thus, for the same reason you can't do: `let obj: Obj = { foo:'bar', blah:'' }`, this code can't compile because there's no compatibility check in this case, as its type is explicitly defined.

Cheers!

Comment: Why is there no compatibility check in the second example? structural typing should apply everywhere no?